# Craft CMS ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

Tags: craft3, docker

I have a remote VM developer environment based on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

I have a development directory where I have checked out a GIT repo for our Craft CMS project.

In this folder is also a docker-compose.yaml file with the following contents:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    image: registry.****.****/****/****/craft-cms/craft-cms:0.0.17
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 3000
      PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE: 64M
      ENVIRONMENT: production
      APP_ID: CraftCMS_3c8ecf73-6e4f-4236-9g9f-cbf83ccbf42a
      SECURITY_KEY: AE6345E2-C645-49A1-8391-C43445BF9524
      DB_DRIVER: mysql
      DB_SERVER: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_DATABASE: craft_web
      DB_USER: admin
      DB_PASSWORD: ****
      DB_TABLE_PREFIX: crft_
      PRIMARY_SITE_URL: http://0.0.0.0:8080
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      SMTP_AUTHENTICATON: 0
      SMTP_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      SMTP_FROM_MAIL: craft@****.***
      SMTP_FROM_NAME: "Craft CMS"
    volumes:
      - ./storage:/app/storage
      - ./web/uploads:/app/web/uploads
      - ./web/cache:/app/web/cache

    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: craft_web
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "exit 0" ]
      interval: 2s
      retries: 5

  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]

volumes:
  db_data:
```

As a result of this I have 3 docker containers:

- craft cms
- maria db
- redis

I was given a mysql dump file, which I have imported into the correct table on the maria db container (I can see unstyled text and articles on http://localhost:8080).

I was also given a copy of an web/uploads folder which I copied into the working directory on the remote VM and I can see unstyled images on http://localhost:8080.

On my local machine (for example at home or in the office) I have VS Code, and I connect to the development machine through SSH (in VS Code). I am also forwarding port http://localhost:8080 so that I can view it in the browser on my local machine.

Problem:

Content at http://localhost:8080 is unstyled and unformatted and no CSS is being honored.

All links on http://localhost:8080 are in the format:

- http://0.0.0.0:8080/about/
- http://0.0.0.0:8080/blog/
- http://0.0.0.0:8080/press/

Clicking on any of these links results in a browser error:

> This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8080/blog/
> might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
> web address. ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

When trying to log in at http://localhost:8080/admin/login

The login form is again unstyled and unformatted. After entering username and password the following error is shown:

Unable to verify your data submission

Any advice on the issue or multiple issues would be greatly appreciated.

My assumption is that there are multiple issues at play here.

Looking at the craft cms docker container log yields the following:

```
2022-12-08 21:26:41 [-][-][0a5bc28b4e91d984c32aa4abd991a3fc][error][yii\web\HttpException:400] yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Ihre Dateneingabe konnte nicht überprüft werden oder ist ungültig. in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:223
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(133): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#1 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UsersController.php(136): craft\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(176): craft\controllers\UsersController->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#3 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#4 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(293): yii\base\Module->runAction('users/login', Array)
#5 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(602): craft\web\Application->runAction('users/login', Array)
#6 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(272): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#8 /app/web/index.php(23): yii\base\Application->run()
#9 {main}
2022-12-08 21:26:41 [-][-][0a5bc28b4e91d984c32aa4abd991a3fc][info][application] $_GET = []

$_POST = [
    'username' => '****.****'
    'password' => '••••••'
]

$_FILES = []

$_COOKIE = [
    'PHPSESSID' => '0a5bc28b4e91d984c32aa4abd991a3fc'
    'CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN' => '••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••'
    '_gcl_au' => '1.1.1750554919.1670451183'
    '_ga' => 'GA1.1.822992605.1670451183'
    'ln_or' => 'd'
    '_ga_DDWMD51NF0' => 'GS1.1.1670529561.4.1.1670531099.0.0.0'
]

$_SESSION = [
    '__flash' => []
    '323a474c85c2f753cb324a5fd06e3e40__returnUrl' => 'http://localhost:8080/admin'
]

$_SERVER = [
    'SMTP_AUTHENTICATON' => '0'
    'REDIS_PORT' => '6379'
    'PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE' => '20M'
    'HOSTNAME' => 'd1fb48426168'
    'DB_PORT' => '3306'
    'PHP_INI_DIR' => '/usr/local/etc/php'
    'PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION' => '128'
    'SHLVL' => '1'
    'HOME' => '/home/www-data'
    'ENVIRONMENT' => 'production'
    'DB_DATABASE' => 'craft_****'
    'PHP_LDFLAGS' => '-Wl,-O1 -pie'
    'PHP_OPCACHE_INTERNED_STRINGS_BUFFER' => '16'
    'DB_TABLE_PREFIX' => '***_'
    'PHP_CFLAGS' => '-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
    'PHP_OPCACHE_ENABLE' => '1'
    'PHP_VERSION' => '8.1.9'
    'PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS' => '3000'
    'GPG_KEYS' => '528995BFEDFBA7191D46839EF9BA0ADA31CBD89E 39B641343D8C104B2B146DC3F9C39DC0B9698544 F1F692238FBC1666E5A5CCD4199F9DFEF6FFBAFD'
    'PHP_CPPFLAGS' => '-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
    'PHP_ASC_URL' => 'https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.9.tar.xz.asc'
    'PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE' => '64M'
    'PHP_URL' => 'https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.9.tar.xz'
    'MOZJPEG_BUILD_DEPS' => 'autoconf     automake     build-base     libtool     nasm     pkgconf     tar'
    'APP_ID' => 'CraftCMS_2b8dcf63-6e3f-4226-9f9f-cbf73ccaf42a'
    'PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME' => '120'
    'PHP_OPCACHE_REVALIDATE_FREQ' => '0'
    'PATH' => '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
    'SMTP_FROM_NAME' => 'Craft CMS'
    'DB_DRIVER' => 'mysql'
    'SMTP_FROM_MAIL' => '****@****.***'
    'PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT' => '256M'
    'LD_PRELOAD' => '/usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so'
    'SECURITY_KEY' => '••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••'
    'PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_WASTED_PERCENTAGE' => '10'
    'PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_ACCELERATED_FILES' => '10000'
    'PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS' => '0'
    'REDIS_HOST' => 'redis'
    'DB_PASSWORD' => '••••••'
    'DB_SERVER' => 'db'
    'PHPIZE_DEPS' => 'autoconf      dpkg-dev dpkg       file        g++         gcc         libc-dev        make        pkgconf         re2c'
    'PWD' => '/app'
    'PHP_SHA256' => '53477e73e6254dc942b68913a58d815ffdbf6946baf61a1f8ef854de524c27bf'
    'PRIMARY_SITE_URL' => 'http://0.0.0.0:8080'
    'PHP_OPCACHE_FAST_SHUTDOWN' => '1'
    'DB_USER' => 'admin'
    'SMTP_HOST' => '127.0.0.1'
    'MOZJPEG_VERSION' => '3.3.1'
    'SUPERVISOR_ENABLED' => '1'
    'SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME' => 'php-fpm'
    'SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME' => 'php-fpm'
    'USER' => 'www-data'
    'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'PHPSESSID=0a5bc28b4e91d984c32aa4abd991a3fc; CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN=1d5a1d442e82a5c835eb137c07e4c51ea63bb95c0f452f8493c1587b6cfd1988a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A16%3A%22CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A40%3A%22xSLdayRTYgbPAwAUMCkMrmPD0yKKWtxG7TZ0p0U4%22%3B%7D; _gcl_au=1.1.1750554919.1670451183; _ga=GA1.1.822992605.1670451183; ln_or=d; _ga_DDWMD51NF0=GS1.1.1670529561.4.1.1670531099.0.0.0'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'de,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate, br'
    'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://localhost:8080/admin/login'
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST' => 'document'
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER' => '?1'
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE' => 'navigate'
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE' => 'same-origin'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    'HTTP_ORIGIN' => 'http://localhost:8080'
    'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => '1'
    'HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM' => '\"Windows\"'
    'HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE' => '?0'
    'HTTP_SEC_CH_UA' => '\"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"108\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"108\"'
    'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0'
    'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH' => '39'
    'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive'
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'localhost:8080'
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/app/web/index.php'
    'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200'
    'SERVER_NAME' => '_'
    'SERVER_PORT' => '8080'
    'SERVER_ADDR' => '172.19.0.4'
    'REMOTE_PORT' => '36954'
    'REMOTE_ADDR' => '172.19.0.1'
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'nginx/1.22.0'
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1'
    'REQUEST_SCHEME' => 'http'
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1'
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/app/web'
    'DOCUMENT_URI' => '/index.php'
    'REQUEST_URI' => '/admin/login'
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/index.php'
    'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '39'
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST'
    'QUERY_STRING' => ''
    'FCGI_ROLE' => 'RESPONDER'
    'PHP_SELF' => '/index.php'
    'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1670531201.7026
    'REQUEST_TIME' => 1670531201
    'argv' => []
    'argc' => 0
]
```

How it looks in the browser (no styling, no layout):

[image]

Console Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested here is the solution:

The problem was that in the docker-compose.yaml file the PRIMARY_SITE_URL was set to http://0.0.0.0:8080 - this will not work when forwarding ports over SSH as I need to do.

Changing the value to http://localhost:8080 worked and allowed all resources and pages to be loaded.